# Bug with chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am building a Chrome extension and am trying to send a message to my event background.js page from inside of `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()`. For some reason the message will not send to my content script...

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 var responseObj = new Object();
 if(request.screenshotRequest == true){
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({ format: "png"}, function(dataUrl){
    responseObj.screenshotRequest = dataUrl;
    alert(sendResponse);
    sendResponse(responseObj);
   });
  }
});
```

My `manifest.json` allows for the correct permissions to allow this message passing to happen. When I try and pass messages using `sendResponse()` outside of the `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()` the message passes correctly and I can access it from the content script. Any idea why this isn't passing?

**UPDATE**: `alert(sendResponse);` proves that `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTabs()` has access to `sendResponse` because the object is correctly displayed in the alert message.

Answer (score 4):

I dug into the console of the unpacked extension (apparently it is different from the regular extension's console: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)) and it said that `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` needed to return true if `sendResponse` was called inside of a callback in the function. It worked!